# Linear regression in python goes seriously wrong with completely wrong regression line

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

Hi everyone I was practicing linear regression on a dataset from kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/sohier/calcofi, bottle.csv), and I try to implement it in the following way:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv("bottle.csv")
df

df1 = df.loc[:,"T_degC":"Salnty"]
df1 = df1.dropna()

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
X = df1["T_degC"]
y = df1["Salnty"]
X = X.values
type(X)
y = y.values
type(y)


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size = 0.4)
lm = LinearRegression()

X_train = X_train.reshape(-1,1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(-1,1)
y_train = y_train.reshape(-1,1)

lm.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

**The problem occurs when I look at the intercepts and the coefficient, which are:**

```
lm.intercept_
lm.coef_
```

which turn out to be 34.4 and -0.05 respectively. But then consider the scatter plot of the X and y variables:

```
plt.scatter(X_train, y_train)
```

It definitely does not look like a negatively-sloped line can be the regression line of this distribution. Thus, I wonder what I may have done wrong that leads to this result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a very interesting case study!

It appears the **regression line is in fact right** and **your eyes (and your plot) are deceiving you**.

The scatter plot you're producing looks like this:
[image: Scatter plot with alpha=1]

Sure looks like a positive slope, right?  Right?
Well, no. There are so many points here, that *it's impossible to see where the most points are*. It might be well the case that the most points would show a downward slope, but they are all on top of each other, and a 'few' other points that are not on top of each other show an upward slope.

#### A better plot: lower the visual overlap

To test that, I plotted the points with a much lower opacity and a smaller marker size (so the amount of overlap would be reduced:

```
plt.scatter(X_train, y_train, alpha=0.002, s=1)
plt.show()
```

[image: Scatter plot with less overlap]
Here you can see that in fact most points show a downward slope (although one might also argue a linear correlation is not the best way to model the correlation). Remember that the Linear Regression tries to fit the best *straight* line, which means it follows most points, but will not be able to capture a more difficult pattern that is not straight if there are only a few outliers there.

In fact the linear correlation coefficient is also negative:

```
df1[["T_degC", "Salnty"]].corr()
#          T_degC    Salnty
#T_degC  1.000000 -0.505266
#Salnty -0.505266  1.000000
```

#### Conclusion

So in short:
 1. Your regression line appears to be correct
 2. Make sure you're looking at the right plot - if all points are on top of each other, a scatter plot may not be optimal.

#### Edit: visual confirmation

One more plot: the scatter plot with your regression on top of it:
[image: scatter plot with regression on top of it]

That seems reasonable (for a straight line), doesn't it?

Perhaps another plot would be more easy to look at with so many points any way:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.jointplot(x='T_degC', y='Salnty', data=df1, kind='hex')
```

[image: hexbin jointplot]

The jointplot explicitly visualizes the overlap by coloring the parts of the graph where there are many points more strongly. This again confirms there is a downward trend, but there are a (relatively small) number of other points that go against that trend.
Hope that helps!

Comment: I am amazed by the comprehensiveness of your answer. I understand it now completely. Thank you very much.